# Can the boot USB get infected if PC is infected?

Tags: windows, usb, windows-11, virus, malware

I want to create a Windows 11 boot USB stick. That's not the problem though as this is easy with the Microsoft provided tool.
What I do want to know is, let's assume your computer is infected, you try to clean up the infection as good as possible and the 4 reputable scanners (Bitdefender or Kaspersky, adwcleaner, hitman pro, ESET free online scanner) find no more detections. I assume there might be either some hidden malware etc. running undetected. Anyways, if you created a Windows 11 boot stick from such a machine, would the medium also get the infection of the potential malware and thus infecting the future "clean reinstall" of Win 11 or "do not worry"? And why?

Comment: I agree with @LPChip's answer, still *ideally* you'd use a different PC to create the Windows USB boot stick.

Comment: But wouldn't another pc, especially if you don't know the browsing habits of the user is, just be like the situation with infected pc?  The other pc could have been infected previously before aswell. So the only possible way to create iso is from a new laptop or if you buy another windows copy then ?

Comment: Okay you win: destroy the infected PC physically. Burn it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen well I would if I had the money but as a broke person, this saddly out of the question.

Comment: I was being sarcastic. The best virus is one that does not raise suspicion and that can not be detected. So then yes, a PC can be infected without you knowing. So then answer is, you can *never* trust any PC to create the USB boot stick. That seems to be what you want to argue and I can not argue against that.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it shouldn't, but there are no guarantees.

The MediaCreationTool downloads an .ISO file and writes the content of that ISO file to the USB stick bit by bit. This in itself will not allow the data to be altered.

The USB stick is then mounted, and this is the moment something could happen to the data.

Its also possible that any possible infection infects MediaCreationTool the moment you launch it and if it is specifically targetting this program, it could alter its behavior in a way to spread itself.

Although it is highly unlikely, in theory it is possible and therefor my suggestion is going to be: Always use a pc that shows no signs of infections.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to post essentially the same answer. It is very unlikely but there are no guarantees. Use a clean computer to generate the boot-stick to be absolutely sure the boot-stick is clean.

Comment: This is quite interesting.  Let's continue with the scenario I wrote above (infected pc,reputable scanners used and possibly eliminated all threats so no detections but unusure if pc is still infected). So if I should use a pc that shows no signs of infection I could theoretically also just use "my own" pc as it shows no more signs after all the reputable scanners did their work. I'm not sure how libary pc work but I assume they are like private pcs. Meaning if I'd ask a friend whos pc habits I don't know,pc might possibly infected and I created the iso there then it's the like with my pc?

Comment: A theoretical infection might still happen unless I buy a new windows or a new laptop as those would be garantueed without possible infections (unless you count the bloatware in laptops).

Comment: The reason I wrote no signs of infection, is that when a pc does not feel sluggish and it is likely not infected with a virus, then you are safe. A virus that wants to spread will negatively affect the pc into where you will notice it sooner or later. It is hard for a pc to get affected nowadays, so if a pc feels good for the last weeks, then you can make that iso no problem.

Comment: @LPChip thank you. is there a way I can write you a dm here? I don't want to spam the forum or the threads with potentially useless stupid questions. I do only have 1 more question and you give informative replies and seem knowledgeable.

Comment: @Idontknowbasics - There is no direct chat capability on a Stack Exchange community.  Trying to reach out or even providing private support is strongly discouraged. The entire idea behind this community is to ask questions, that other individuals might have, so they can be answered.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for making me aware of it. i didn't know. I will just create a topic later on.